# NHibernate / Linq creating invalid SQL with SQL CE

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-ce, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 3.1 with SQL CE 4 (Using the MsSqlCe40Dialect). Using Linq to produce queries.

If I use String.Contains, String.StartsWith or String.EndsWith, invalid SQL is produced.

For example:

```
Session.Query<User>.Where(user => user.Name.Contains("Joe"))
```

produces SQL like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM User WHERE (User.Name like ('%'||@p0||'%'))
```

This is somewhat simplified from the actual SQL produced, but the problem is in the extra `'||...||'`

I expect this is a problem with the SQL CE dialect, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas for a fix / workaround?

Comment: Can you use HQL for this particular case?

Comment: This is actually part of a larger query. I'd like to keep it just Linq if possible. Are you aware of any way to combine Linq with HQL or criteria?

Comment: write the entire thing using HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed shortly after the 3.1 release ([in this commit](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/41dbbf58c6a0c45d5cb4e1404e2d236272e30bb0)). Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade NHibernate due to other dependencies. In the meantime, I have worked around the problem by subclassing `MsSqlCe40Dialect` with the following code:

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Dialect.Function;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class CustomMsSqlCe40Dialect : MsSqlCe40Dialect
    {
        public CustomMsSqlCe40Dialect ()
        {
            RegisterFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.String, "(", "+", ")"));
        }
    }
}
```